# Ampl Cplex solve error

Tags: cplex, ampl

Why do I get the following message everytime I try to solve a model with CPLEX:

```
ampl: option solver Cplex;
ampl: model Anchor_QP.mod;
ampl: solve;

Incorrect usage. Correct command syntax is:
   Cplex
or
   Cplex -f <commandfile>
or
   Cplex -c "<command1>" "<command2>" ... 
Exiting
Error executing "solve" command:
can't open C:\Users\ozgutr\AppData\Local\Temp\at16996.sol
```

Answer (score 2):

The thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/TQm39kQ-lc8) suggests that you should use:

```
option solver cplexamp;
```

Instead of:

```
option solver cplex;
```

It also says:

> Looks like you are running a command-line version of CPLEX rather than CPLEX for AMPL.
>   "cplexamp" is the name of the CPLEX-for-AMPL executable distributed by IBM.

I have not tried this personally, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you should write "cplex" instead of "Cplex", because AMPL is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I have AMPL community edition one and I had to activate my license running this command in AMP ide

*ampl: shell "amplkey activate --uuid **your_license**" ;*

It also says on the website that you can download the amp.lic file from there and place it manually into your AMPL folder.